# Smoothly extending a smooth function.

Tags: differential-geometry, continuity

Ok so maybe it is just late but I am embarrassed to say that I am a little stumped by this question which is noted by the professor to just be a "calculus exercise".

Anyway, let $f$ and $g$ be smooth functions $U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $0\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Let $(x,y_1,\ldots,y_n)=(x,y)$ be the coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and suppose $f(0,y)=g(0,y)=0$ for all $y$. Suppose furthermore that $g(x,y)\neq 0$ for all $x \neq 0$ and that $\partial g/\partial x(0,y)\neq 0$ for all $y$. Show that the function $h=f/g$ defined when $g\neq 0$ extends uniquely to a continuous function $\tilde{h}$ defined on all of $U$ and $\tilde{h}$ is smooth. Write a formula for $\tilde{h}(0,y)$.

So far:

So I extend $h$ in the obvious way $\tilde{h}(0,y)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} h(x,y)$. L'Hopital's rule gives that this limit exists and it equals $f_x/g_x(0,y)$. I am a bit stumped on continuity (on the $y$ axis, it is clear elsewhere), I'm not sure I can show it directly. I was hoping to show that $\tilde{h}$ is differentiable at $(0,y)$ as that starts smoothness and implies continuity but I didn't really get anywhere.

Any thoughts?

I am happy that $\tilde{h}$ extends uniquely by the way and as for the formula I have a hint, it is just continuity and smoothness which vexes.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: you can use Heine definition of continuity. It states that function is continuous at point $P$ if the limit is the same for every sequence converging to $P$. When you take a sequence of points that don't belong $\lbrace x = 0 \rbrace$ and converges to $(0, y^\ast)$,$\;$ you may write $h(x, y)$ as $\frac{f(x, y) - f(0, y^\ast)}{x} \colon \frac{g(x, y) - g(0, y^\ast)}{x}$. Something like mean value theorem must do the rest of the job.

Also, I'm not very sure that $\tilde{h}$ must be smooth too. The value of $\tilde{h}$ at $x=0$ is a superposition of two continuous functions ($f_x$ and $g_x$) which are not necessarily smooth.

Comment: The OP probably meant "smooth" as $C^\infty$. In my experience, about 50% of people use unqualified "smooth" for $C^1$; the other 50% for $C^\infty$. And 90% of them assume that everyone follows their convention.